# $f, g: Q \rightarrow R$ be bounded such that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x \in Q$ Show that $\int_{Q} f \leq \int_{\Omega} g$ DON't use Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

- Let $f, g: Q \rightarrow R$ be bounded functions such that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x \in Q$ Show that $\underline{\int_{Q}} f \leq \underline{\int_{Q}}g$ and $\bar{\int}_{Q} f \leq \bar{\int}_{Q} g$ DON't use Fubini's theorem.

My Attempt. Assume $f,g$ are integrable. Consider $f(x)-g(x)\leq 0$ for $x\in Q$.Then $m(f)-m(g)\leq 0$ where $m(f)=inf\{f(x): x\in R\}$, similarly for $m(g)$. Then multiple $v(R)$ to $m(f)-m(g)\leq 0$ where $v(R)$ is the volume of $R$, then we get $(m(f)-m(g)) v(R)\leq 0$.

$$\sum_{Q} (m(f)-m(g)) v(R)\leq 0$$

that is,

$$\underline{\int_{Q}} f \leq \underline{\int_{Q}}g.$$

**May you check my attempt, if it is false, may you help to prove?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is not what the lower and upper integrals are (unless you are working in a very different context). Usually you would have 
$$
\underline{\int_{Q}} f =\sup\,\sum_j f_j\,\Delta x_j,
$$
where the supremum  is taken over all partitions of $Q$, and $f_j=\inf\{f(x):\ x\in[x_j,x_{j+1}]\}$.

So first you show that $f_j\leq g_j$ for any $j$ and any partition. For this, you have $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for any $x$, so $f_j\leq g(x)$ for any $x\in [x_j,x_{j+1}]$. Now take the infimum on the right and you get $f_j\leq g_j$. From here you get
$$
\sum_j f_j\,\Delta_j\leq \sum_j g_j\,\Delta_j
$$
for any partition. Now, since the supremum is an upper bound, you get 
$$
\sum_j f_j\,\Delta_j\leq \underline{\int_{Q}} g 
$$
for any partition. And now the integral on the right is an upper bound so it has to be greater than the supremum: 
$$
\underline{\int_{Q}} f \leq \underline{\int_{Q}} g. 
$$

Comment: Ahh yess thanks for answer and comments